# Is it viable to purchase a ".com" domain while another company in the UK owns the ".co" version? Help!

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains, business

I'm starting a business and I'm looking into purchasing a domain name for my business but the problem I see is that another company in the UK (United Kingdom) owns the exact name of my business but in ".co", and I'm looking to purchase the ".com" which is actually available to purchase. Will this be a problem when people search for my company name?

Comment: Look at ICANN's UDRP regulation in place for .COM domain names and how your domain could be disputed if it looks confusingly similar to a trademarked name and if you use it in bad faith. If you want to avoid problems, just use another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the problem lies not in the technical part of which site shows up. The real liability lies in whether the domain name is trademarked. You run the risk of lawsuits.